# git pull image folder only once

Tags: git, gitignore

I have decided to use `git` for my project management. I am getting used to it but i have one question.

I have set up a project on System A with some image file . Images are rarely going to change so i decided to place images folder to `gitignore`.

When I pull/clone project to other system I don't get that images. I know if I add them to `gitignore` it can't be pulled. But for first time cloning images will be needed for project.

I don't want image folder to be tracked by git but any way to sync that image folder ?

Comment: If it's part of the project and it's not a generated file then it should go to the repository. Even if it never changes.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to add the images to your repository.  Using a submodule just adds hassle without any clear benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a separate [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for the images, and track them in the original project. This assumes the repos' images are all in a common subdirectory.

That way, if you want to work in the parent repo, you can clone the parent repo alone, if you want both, you can use `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` to fetch the submodule, and if you want to update the images alone, you can publish to that repo alone.